# ANTLR unclear multiple alternatives

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3

I have this grammar to match simple logical predicates in ANTLR.

```
exp :   or
    ;

or  :   and ('|' or)*
    ;

and :   unit ('&' and)*
    ;

unit    :   '(' or ')' |
        STRING
    ;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

STRING
    :  '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'\'') )* '\''
    ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;
```

I'm getting the warning `Decision can match input such as "'&'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2`, as well as one for the `or` rule. I know that this warning comes up when there ambiguities in the grammar, but I really can't see what the ambiguity is. I also don't understand the warning message because it says the input '&' has multiple alternatives, but '&' by itself shouldn't be a valid input. Can anyone point out the ambiguity? I'm worried that it will mess me up later on when the grammar does become more complex.

Comment: Did you edit your code or the error message? Your error says "Decision", but I think this referring to `and` in your grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instead of this:

```
or  :   and ('|' or)*
    ;

and :   unit ('&' and)*
    ;
```

you want this:

```
or  :   and ('|' and)*
    ;

and :   unit ('&' unit)*
    ;
```

The form you've got is ambiguous because when it's processing that nested `or` (or `and`) it doesn't know if that one should continue repeating, swallowing up the next `|` (or `&`) or if it should return to the outer one and let it process it.